# Output xml escape characters and text using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML similar to this

```
<audit>
     <contextData>
          <name>Auditing</name>
          <values>String</values>
     </contextData>
     <credentials>
               <subjectRoleName>subjectRoleName</subjectRoleName>          
     </credentials>
</audit>
```

I am trying to write an XSL that would output a text with a format similar to below
*************************OUTPUT************************

```
Name=Auditing

<credentials>
      <subjectRoleName>subjectRoleName</subjectRoleName>
</credentials>
```

---

Key here is that output contains text as well some xml from original xml source. I am unable to figure out after lot of research how to create a xsl that can provide output similar to above. Each time I seem to be getting just the values in the output. Have tried using xsl:copy, xsl:copy-of etc.

Thanks a lot for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to get your desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:param name="name-text" select="//contextData/name"/>
  <xsl:text>Name=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$name-text"/><xsl:text>

  </xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="//credentials"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```